# How to move iiwa robot in Drake?

Tags: drake

I'm trying to add a second iiwa robot to my simulation  after figuring out how to add the first one. I'm currently attempting to move the first one using

```
iiwa_robot = plant.GetBodyByName("iiwa_link_0")
        X_B = plant.EvalBodyPoseInWorld(plant_context, iiwa_robot)

        
        tf = RigidTransform(p=[15, 10, 5]) 
plant.SetFreeBodyPose(plant_context,iiwa_robot,X_B.multiply(tf))
```

However I keep getting the error

```
Body 'iiwa_link_0' is not a free floating body
```

I've also tried the other iiwa_links_ which produced the same error. Am I supposed to change something in the sdf file? Is there a better way to do this that I'm just not thinking of?

Comment: SetFreeBodyPose can only move free body. I think your `iiwa_link_0` body is welded to the world and you can change your first iiwa's location when you declare that weldframe using `plant.WeldFrames`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your first IIWA arm, you can call [WeldFrames](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a51239c495a32c1f156964cd2c8410c53) to put the robot at the desired location.

Here is the pseudo code

```py
iiwa1 = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(iiwa_file, "iiwa1")
# Weld the link0 of iiwa1 with the world at a given location.
plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetBodyByName("iiwa_link_0", iiwa1).body_frame(), RigidTransform(p=[15, 10, 5]))
```

You can similarly add the second IIWA arm and weld its link_0 to the world to a different location.

```py
iiwa2 = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(iiwa_file, "iiwa2")
# Weld the link0 of iiwa2 with the world at a given location.
plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetBodyByName("iiwa_link_0", iiwa2).body_frame(), RigidTransform(p=[10, 10, 5]))
```

Comment: I'm getting a duplicate error in AddJoint 

```py AddJoint(): Duplicate joint name 'WorldBody_welds_to_iiwa_link_0'. ```

Comment: Sorry for that. I modified the code. When calling AddModelFromFile, I add a name to the iiwa to differentiate between the two. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: ```sdf_path = FindResourceOrThrow("drake/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/iiwa7/"f"iiwa7_{collision_model}.sdf")```
\n



```parser = Parser(plant)```

\n


    ```iiwa = parser.AddModelFromFile(sdf_path, "iiwa1")```
I added the "iiwa1" to where I called AddModelFromFile, but it seems to be giving the same error...

Comment: Did you add "iiwa2" where you call AddModelFromFile for the second IIWA? I ran the code on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! So I removed the second iiwa for now to see if I can just move one of the iiwa to a new starting position. My code is still outputting the duplicate error though

Comment: What is the call trace of your error? Is it thrown from WeldFrames? I can run the following code and it works fine

sdf_path = FindResourceOrThrow("drake/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/iiwa7/"f"iiwa7_no_collision.sdf")

plant = MultibodyPlant(0.)

parser = Parser(plant)

iiwa = parser.AddModelFromFile(sdf_path, "iiwa1")

plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetBodyByName("iiwa_link_0", iiwa).body_frame())